# Eclipse PDT plugin gives me trouble

Tags: 11.04, java, php, eclipse

Editor of PDT plugin jumbles the code and doesn't take responses in. I tried many things but didn't help at all. I was wondering what you guys are using to develop PHP applications for I am new to PHP. And I am a Java Programmer so I am more experience with Eclipse that is why I need to fix this issue.Below are few things I tried out

1. Reinstall PDT Plugin
2. Checked if Java editor works (it works perfectly)

I am out of solutions now and only think that I can think of is that Eclipse version is giving me trouble. I am using

> Version: Indigo Release
>
> Build id: 20110615-0604
>
> OS : Ubuntu 11.04
>
> PDT Version :  PHP Development Tools (PDT) All-In-One SDK    3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77

I am going to include few screenshots too. The screenshots were taken when I clicked in different places of the screen. And sometimes what I type is not displaying at all. Another thing I want to mention is that I also have Aptana plugin installed and the PHP is not working properly in it too. So PDT plugin might not necessarily be the cause for it. Will removing Aptana for PHP help me?
[image: Clicking around]
[image: Code jumbles up]
[image: Stuff disappears]

I have asked this question on StackOver Flow at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887556/eclipse-pdt-plugin-gives-me-trouble) I hope you don't mind the cross posting...

Comment: You already asked this on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887556/eclipse-pdt-plugin-gives-me-trouble Is it necessarily to duplicate?

Comment: sorry... I thought this might even be a problem with Ubuntu version ....

Comment: read also http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1480 on cross-posting

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and have no problem writing PHP code using the PDT plugin. It might be the Java version you're using. I'm using OpenJDK 64-bit 1.6.0_22.

When programming PHP, you could take a look at [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/). It supports features like refactoring in PHP (Eclipse PDT doesn't).

Comment: I used to work with Netbeans for Java I'll take a look at it... for PHP